# How to select from 2 tables depending on uniqueness values in a column in one table

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I have 2 tables: 
First (Cases) 
Second (Comments)

in one to many relation ; I'm storing the comments of each case in Comments table.

I need to select case information from Cases table which are presented in Comments table, but I want each case to be displayed ONCE ordered by comments added date (cDate)

I tried:

```
SELECT TOP 10  
     Cases.*,  
     comments.cDate  
FROM  
     Cases 
INNER JOIN comments 
     ON Cases.Case_ID = comments.Case_ID 
WHERE comments.Case_ID IN 
        (
           SELECT DISTINCT 
              Case_ID 
           FROM 
             comments
         ) 
 ORDER BY cDate DESC
```

but its retrieving the case multiple times if it has many comments. I need it to appear one time only

---

Thank you all, you helped alot ,, 
I just added

```
Cases.Case_ID IN (SELECT Case_ID FROM comments)
```

and it worked perfectly.

Select statement is like this now:

```
SELECT top 10 Cases.*,
(SELECT MAX(comments.cDate) 
       FROM comments 
       WHERE Cases.Case_ID = comments.Case_ID  ) AS cDate 
FROM Cases
WHERE Cases.Case_ID 
                 IN (SELECT Case_ID FROM comments) 
ORDER BY cDate DESC
```

Thanks once again :)

Comment: Do you want the latest comment per case?

Comment: Yes I need to get recently discussed cases

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all, you helped alot ,, I just added

```
Cases.Case_ID IN (SELECT Case_ID FROM comments)
```

and it worked perfectly.

Select statement is like this now:

```
SELECT top 10 Cases.*,
(SELECT MAX(comments.cDate) 
       FROM comments 
       WHERE Cases.Case_ID = comments.Case_ID  ) AS cDate 
FROM Cases
WHERE Cases.Case_ID 
                 IN (SELECT Case_ID FROM comments) 
ORDER BY cDate DESC
```

Thanks once again :)

Comment: At the very least you could upvote *all* of the answers that helped you arrive at this solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, it looks like you want to use a subquery:

```
SELECT top 10 Cases.*, 
(SELECT MAX(comments.cDate) FROM comments 
           WHERE Cases.Case_ID = comments.Case_ID ) AS cDate
FROM Cases 
ORDER BY cDate DESC
```

Comment: [@Tomek](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9150379/57237) correctly points out that this will return cases that have no comments at all (which was a requirement by OP). He adds the INNER JOIN to comments that corrects that.

Comment: thank you for your replay, this is working well and retrieving unique cases, but even cases that have no comments are retrieved, how can I exclude them?

Answer (score 1):

This will do:

```
SELECT TOP 10
        A.* ,
        (SELECT MAX(C.cDate) FROM comments C WHERE C.Case_ID = A.Case_ID) commDate
FROM    Cases A
        INNER JOIN comments B ON A.Case_ID = B.Case_ID
ORDER BY commDate
```

(@yhw42 query will return Cases which have no comments as well.)

Comment: it still returns the same case many times if it has more than one comment

Answer (score 0):

First some test data:

```
DECLARE @tblCases TABLE(Case_ID INT)
DECLARE @comments TABLE(Case_ID INT,cDate DATETIME)

INSERT INTO @tblCases
SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2

INSERT INTO @comments
SELECT 1,GETDATE() UNION ALL
SELECT 1,GETDATE()-1 UNION ALL
SELECT 2,GETDATE()-2 UNION ALL
SELECT 2,GETDATE()-3
```

Then i would do it like this.

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT
        RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY Case_ID ORDER BY cDate DESC) AS iRank,
        tbl.cDate,
        tbl.Case_ID
    FROM
        @comments AS tbl
)
SELECT TOP 10  
     Cases.*,  
     CTE.cDate  
FROM  
    CTE
    JOIN @tblCases AS Cases
        ON Cases.Case_ID=CTE.Case_ID
WHERE
    CTE.iRank=1
```